# smfart author in title

Tags: titles, document-classes

Upon output of `\maketitle`, the `smfart` class produces something like

> Title
>
> by
>
> Author

Is there anyway I can remove the "by" bit? I think I've seen similar files do it, but I never had access to the latex code.
I checked the documentation but I couldn't find anything helpful.
I guess one could tweak the `.cls` file, but maybe someone knows a better way to do this? (or at least the "correct" way to tweak the `.cls` file?)

Here's a MWE (one needs to have `smfart.cls` file, available here)

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{smfart}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    Very.
\end{abstract}
\title{The Monograph}
\author{Dr Koolaid}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
Wordz.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `smfart` class adds “by” (or a translation thereof) if and only if the macro `\smfbyname` expands to something non empty.

However the redefinition has to be done “at begin document” and `\renewcommand*` *must* be used (note the `*`).

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{smfart}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\smfbyname}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Very.
\end{abstract}

\title{The Monograph}
\author{Dr Koolaid}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

Wordz.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted. awesome. thanks for the quick answer.